# Why GitLab's package registry stores all the assets instead of replacing them?

Tags: nuget, gitlab-ci.yml

I was struggling with GitLab's package registry to pack a custom made NuGet package via gitlab's CI/CD but I don't understand why the same asset is stored multiple times instead of being replaced by the new pushed file? The name and version of these nupkg are the same.

**The `gitlab-ci.yml` I used:**

```yaml
variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: "MyCompany.StandardUtils"
  
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - dotnet pack $PROJECT_NAME.csproj -c Release
    - dotnet nuget add source "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/nuget/index.json" --name gitlab --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text
    - dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/*.nupkg" --source gitlab
  only:
    - master
  environment: production
```

The asset list I got from 3 uploads of the same `.nupkg`:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAfM1.png)

Comment: Works as intended, from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/): "If you publish the same package with the same version multiple times, **each consecutive upload is saved as a separate file**. When installing a package, GitLab serves the most recent file."

Comment: I can't believe I missed that part after reading it all, thank you for the answer.
I wanted to give you the "answer found" green tick but I don't think I can do it in the comments.